# Wordpress Related Posts Code Not Working Live But Is Locally

Tags: php, wordpress

Added related posts snippet to my local site and it works perfectly.

Uploaded to the server - digital ocean - and now brings up white screen of death

```
<?php
<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array('parts/shared/html-header', 'parts/shared/header' ) ); ?>
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

<div class="full-width blog-single-hero hero" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat;background-size:cover;">

 <?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/navigation' ) ); ?>

<div class="container animated fadeInDelay clear">
<div class="full">
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div><!--full-->
</div><!--container-->

</div><!--hero-->

<div class="container blog-index animated fadeInDelay clear">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="single-blog-post <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . ' ';}?>">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<div class="share-icons wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
        <h2>Please Share This Article!</h2>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=593154b67442e0001200a27f&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>
        <div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div>
    </div><!--ends share-->

<div class="related-posts wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
  <h2>Other Posts You May Like!</h2>
    <?php $orig_post = $post; global $post; $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories) {
      $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
      $args=array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=> 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
      );
    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo '<div class="related-posts">';
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      $my_query->the_post();?>
      <div class="four">
        <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <h2><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      </div><!--four-->
    <? } echo '</div>';}}
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div><!--ends related-posts-->

</article>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- container -->
```

any idea why?

this is the single.php file for wordpress

I have this working on another website using wordpress with same code but on different server, could this be the reason?

Comment: Have you checked the error log yet? If you haven't, please [follow these instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging) (omit the SCRIPT_DEBUG line) and edit your question to add the error/warning messages.

Comment: By the way, the parameter `caller_get_posts` was replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts` since WP version 3.1. (see [WP_Query - Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) for more).